# Android, native app can't start when I use std::vector::push_back()

Tags: android, stdvector, android-stlport

I need to use the vector container in my native application (it's cocos-2dx framework)
So, I've added

> APP_STL := stlport_static

to `Application.mk`
Then

> `#include <vector>`

in header file for the class which uses vector
Define the variable as

> `std::vector<cocos2d::CCPoint*> *m_VertexAnchors;`

And then do this

> `m_VertexAnchors->push_back(point);`

`point` here is actually `CCPoint* point`
And when I run my app I just see the black screen than it disappears after 2-3 sec without any message.
The last message in logcat is (filter by application name and with verbose level)

> 04-01 13:22:57.068: D/dalvikvm(2939): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 64K, 47%
>   free 2887K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 40ms

and there are no errors before just messages about loading libs. And I've not seen anything strange in the main log.
Then when I commented out

> `m_VertexAnchors->push_back(point);`

the app works fine.

So, is there anything I've missed, if no how could I debug this (I use Eclipse with sequoyah plugin)

Will appreciate any help or suggestions, thanks.

Comment: How do you initialise `m_vertexAnchors` and `point`?

Comment: I receive point as a function parameter, so it must be correct. But about m_vertexAnchors I'm not sure, how should I init it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using `m_vertexAnchors` you must initialize it correctly:

```
m_VertexAnchors = new std::vector<cocos2d::CCPoint*>();
```

you must remember to `delete` it when no longer required.

If you can avoid dynamically allocating the `vector` then declare it as:

```
std::vector<cocos2d::CCPoint*> m_VertexAnchors;
```

and use it:

```
m_VertexAnchors.push_back(point);
```

Comment: That's it. I've added new to my constructor and delete to destructor, and it works, thanks!